# Error installing gem install sass windows 7

Tags: ruby, sass

please help me to resolve this installation error.
first install ruby "Ruby 2.1.5" and then wrote in cmd "gem install sass" but got an error

**C:\Ruby21**

> C:>ruby -v ruby 2.1.5p273 (2014-11-13 revision 48405) [i386-mingw32]
>
> C:>gem install sass ERROR:  Could not find a valid gem 'sass' (>= 0),
>   here is why:
>             Unable to download data from https://rubygems.org/ - Errno::ETIMEDOUT:  Se produjo un error durante el intento de conexi?n
>   ya que la parte conectada no  respondi? adecuadamente tras un periodo
>   de tiempo, o bien se produjo un error e n la conexi?n establecida ya
>   que el host conectado no ha podido responder. - con nect(2) for
>   "api.rubygems.org" port 443 (https://api.rubygems.org/latest_specs.4
>   .8.gz)

I have removed the proxy and have even given me free ip and permissions to install "gem install sass" but the error keeps coming but now appears to be another

```
C:\Users\usuario>gem install sass
ERROR:  Could not find a valid gem 'sass' (>= 0), here is why:
          Unable to download data from https://rubygems.org/ - SSL_connect retur
ned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server certificate B: certificate verify failed (
https://api.rubygems.org/latest_specs.4.8.gz)
```

Comment: Do you have internet connection?

Comment: obviously if I have internet connection

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I got friends thanks to https://www.youtube.com/user/johanricardo1108/about

that have:
gem sources -a http://rubygems.org/
comfirmed and then this:
gem install sass

```
C:\Ruby21>gem sources -a http://rubygems.org/
https://rubygems.org is recommended for security over http://rubygems.org/

Do you want to add this insecure source? [yn]  y
http://rubygems.org/ added to sources

C:\Ruby21>gem install sass
Fetching: sass-3.4.12.gem (100%)
Successfully installed sass-3.4.12
Parsing documentation for sass-3.4.12
Installing ri documentation for sass-3.4.12
Done installing documentation for sass after 6 seconds
WARNING:  Unable to pull data from 'https://rubygems.org/': SSL_connect returned
=1 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server certificate B: certificate verify failed (htt
ps://api.rubygems.org/latest_specs.4.8.gz)
1 gem installed

C:\Ruby21>sass -v
Sass 3.4.12 (Selective Steve)
```

Comment: Thanks, you saved my day ;)

Comment: Great little tip!! :)

Answer (score 0):

Check out your firewall and network connections. I have this problem when connecting through the network of company where I work, because we have a proxy that blocks those.

Check for these addresses and ports to be open in a firewall:

```
rubygems.org 443 
github.com 443 
s3.amazonaws.com 443
```

Comment: I suspect, because I'm actually in the office and security policies apply here, but I should ask? if I have some blocked port? or if you have to make a special configuration?

Comment: I've updated my answer with some ports and addresses I believe should be open in order to download gems. But don't take it for granted because proxies are cross-functional and don't often work as a simple firewall.

Comment: I often connect a 3G modem or a guest Wifi network in order to just download and update them.

Comment: I have removed the proxy and have even given me free ip and permissions to install "gem install sass" but the error keeps coming but now appears to be another   "C:\Users\usuario>gem install sass
ERROR:  Could not find a valid gem 'sass' (>= 0), here is why:
          Unable to download data from https://rubygems.org/ - SSL_connect retur
ned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server certificate B: certificate verify failed (
https://api.rubygems.org/latest_specs.4.8.gz)
 "